# Can not access to the method of another class from a class in php

Tags: php, class, methods

I have class for database   which is like this

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo ,
            $_query ,
            $_results, 
            $_error=false, 
            $_count=0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo= new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
            //echo 'connected';

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        }

        public static function getInstance(){
            if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
                self::$_instance = new DB();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }
         public function get($table,$where){
            return $this->action("select *",$table,$where);
        }

}
```

And I have another class from where I need to use the DB class

```
class Validate {
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db     = null;

    public function _construct (){

        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

   public function check($source , $items = array()){
            $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value,array($item, '=',$value)); 
  }
```

My problem is when I run this program I got an error like this

**Call to a member function get() on a non-object**

What is the reason for this error as I already have an instance of DB class in my constructor .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Validate` constructor isn't defined correctly, and thus isn't being called.

```
public function _construct (){
```

No constructor call means `$this->_db` is returning `null` in your `check()` method. It should simply have another underscore:

```
public function __construct() {
                ^
```

[Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) in PHP

Comment: Thanks a lot , this problem was killing me